# How to override focused button element style android?

Tags: android

I have a button on one of my tabs fragment by default that fragment is not visible. To achieve the fragment with button you need to swipe. So how can I make the button focused with different style when the fragment opens? (for example if focused make red border around element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When its about border you may check [Shape drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape) . For *different style* you may check [Custom background](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#CustomBackground) selector documentation . Lets try the below steps followed by the documentation-

1. Create two drawables into `res/drawable/` directory of your project .

*button_focused.xml* for showing red border while the button would be focused .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="10px" android:color="#DD0E0E" />
   </shape>
```

*button_pressed.xml* for pressed mode.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="10px" android:color="#2196F3" />
   </shape>
```

2. Create another drawable named *button_custom.xml* for `selector` .

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
        android:state_focused="true" />
   </selector>
   ```
3. Define *button_custom.xml* as the value of attribute of button background .

   ```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test Button"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"/>
   ```
4. Now its time to set focus on button while user will swipe . So implement `onViewCreated` method inside your fragement if it already not overridden . Then address the button and set it focus-able .

   ```
     @Override
   public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button button = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button_test);
    button.setFocusable(true);
    button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    button.requestFocus();
   }
   ```

Comment: thank you very much but I'm not sure why android:state_focused="true" does not change anything. Does this focus trigger when we use keyboard switching between elements?

Comment: Did you tried `button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true)` ?

Comment: what the difference between setFocusabe and setFocusableInTouchMode? The thing is I need to handle it only in case user use hard keyboard connected to the device and switch elements with actual buttons

Comment: To force focus to a specific view, call `requestFocus()`.  setFocusabe for keypad+touch but sometime not for all views . setFocusableInTouchMode for touch mode.

Comment: could you please explain what means touchMode and do I understand right that by default its off?

Comment: According to the documentation when user touch the touchable screen the device will enter the  touch mode  , on the other hand when user hit keypad key the device will exit touch mode. Clearly explained here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#touch-mode

Comment: `button.setFocusable(true);
  button.requestFocus();` this part will trigger for keypad .

 `button.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
 button.requestFocus();` this part will trigger for touch mode .

so hope above answer will cover different user behaviour .

You can check one by one part with emulator , use `hw.dPad = yes` to use D'pad / directional
pad in avd config.ini . to open D'pad Ctrl+Shift+D .